# Python psutil version conflict for Terminator on Centos 7

Tags: centos, python, gnome-terminator

This issue started after latest updates installation, probably in last 2-3 days.
When I try to open Terminator I get error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/terminator", line 23, in <module>
    import psutil
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/psutil/__init__.py", line 181, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: version conflict: '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/psutil/_psutil_linux.so' C extension module was built for another version of psutil (different than 2.2.1)
```

I am using Centos 7.2 (64 bit).
I did not installed any other software or any other python libraries in last one month.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into the same problem and worked around it by installing the version of `psutil` listed in the error.

`sudo pip install psutil==2.2.1`